# Why is iAd banner automatically unpausing my game?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

In my SpriteKit game I am using an iAd banner like so:

**In GameScene.h:**

```
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>
#import <iAd/iAd.h>
@interface GameScene : SKScene <ADBannerViewDelegate>
@end
```

**In GameScene.m:**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) ADBannerView *adView;
```

*in the createSceneContents method (called by didMoveToView):*

```
self.adView = [[ADBannerView alloc]initWithFram: CGRectZero];
self.adView.frame =CGRectOffset(self.adView.frame, 0, 0.0f);
self.adView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:self.addView];
```

*in the pauseGame method (that I use to pause the game when the pause button is pressed):*

```
self.world.paused = YES;
```

*in the bannerViewActionShouldBegin method:*

```
self.world.paused = YES;
return YES;
```

*in the bannerViewActionDidFinish:*

```
self.world.paused = YES;
```

The problem is, that when I pause before clicking on the add. And then click on the add and go back, the game should still be paused and waiting for me to be unpaused. Instead it unpauses for a second and then pauses. The second pause is caused by *bannerViewActionDidFinish* and if I remove that the game just unpauses automatically; The game continues to run when the add is up. Somehow the add overrides my code and unpauses everything. I have no clue what to do.